# Proof that max{|x|,|y|} ist a norm

Tags: normed-spaces

My supervisor complains about the clarity of my mathematical proofs. Is this clear? Any suggestions how to improove it?

We need to show that we have

(i)$||x||=0 \iff x=0$

(ii)$||\lambda x||=|\lambda| ||x||$

(iii) $||x+y|| \leq ||x||+||y||$

$(i)$

We show the implication in both directions:

$ max\{|x|,|y|\}=0 $

$\Rightarrow |x| \leq 0 \land |y| \leq 0$
Let's consider wlog $x$. We have $0 \leq |x| \leq 0$. The absolute amount is always positive. We show this now. Because of the linearity it follows that $0 \leq x$ und $x \leq 0$. If $0 \leq x$ then $|x| \geq 0$. Let $x \leq 0$. If $x=0$ we have due to $0 \geq 0$ $|0| =0\geq 0$ that the norm is positive. If $x<0$ then the output will be $-x$. But form $x<0$ it follows that $0<-x$. So we have $|x| \geq 0$.

From $0 \leq x \leq 0$ it follows $x=0$ because of Antisymmetry.

The same thing for $y$.

We will show now the opposite direction. Let $x=0$ and $y=0$. $0$ is a maximum of the set $\{0,0\}$, then $0\in M$ and for all elements we have $0 \leq 0$.

(ii) Homogeneity

Let's look at $\{|\alpha x|,|\alpha y|\}$ and let wolog $|\alpha x|$ be the maximum of the set. We have also generally that $|xy|=|x||y|$. We will go through the cases each.

Let $x,y$ be positive then the statement ist true and if $x$ or $y$ $=0$.

If one of them is negative say $y$ then we have $|x(-y)|=|x||(-y)|=xy=|x||y|$

If both of them are negative we find that
$|(-x)(-y)|=|xy|=xy=|x||y|$
We have that
$ max\{|\alpha x|,|\alpha y|\}$

$=max\{|\alpha||x|, |\alpha||y|\}$

Say that $|\alpha||x|$ is the maximum. This means we have

$|e_i| \leq |\alpha||x|$

$\Rightarrow \frac{|e_i|}{|\alpha|} \leq |x|$

Thus we have $x$ the maximum of the set in which $e_i$s are divided by $\alpha$ were meaning
$max\{|x|,|y|\}=x$

Finally we find
$|\alpha| max\{|x|,|y|\}=|\alpha||x|=|\alpha x|=max\{|\alpha x|,|\alpha y|\}$
and thus
$|\alpha|max\{|x|,|y|\}=max\{|\alpha x|,|\alpha y|\}$

$(iii)$ Triangle Inequality

We need the following Lemma. Let $e_i$ be the elements of a finite set and the $(e')_i$ elements of another set and we have $e_i \leq (e')_i$ for all $i$.

Then the first maximum is less than or equal to the latter maximum.

We have $m \leq (e')_i \leq m'$
and thus $m \leq m'$

The second Lemma is
$|x+y| \leq |x|+|y| $

We proof first that
$x \leq |x| $
Let $x>0$ then we have $x \leq |x|$ and if $x\leq 0$ then we find $x \leq 0 \leq |x|$.

We apply $-x$ and find

$x \leq |x| $

$-x \leq |x|$

$x+y > 0$

$|x+y| \leq x+y \leq |x| + |y|$

and if $x+y \leq 0$

then we find

$ |x+y|=-(x+y)=-x-y\leq |x|+|y| $

As a third Lemma we need that if all elements of a finite set are of the form $(e'')_i=e_i+(e')_i$ we find that

$ max\{e_i\}+max\{(e)'_i\} \leq max\{e_i+(e')_i\}$

This is because

$(e_i)+(e)'_i \leq m+m' \leq max\{e_i+(e')_i\}$

The $e_i$s and $(e')_i$s are elements and $m$ and $m'$ the corresponding maximas.

from these three lemmas the proof is relatively easy and we have that

$ max \{ |x_1+x_2|, |y_1+y_2|\} \leq max \{|x_1|+|x_2|,|y_1|+|y_2|\}$

because $|x_1|+|x_2| \leq |x_1+x_2|$.

and finally
$ \leq max \{ |x_1|,|y_1|\}+max \{|x_2|,|y_2|\}$

Comment: Please don't rely on the title of your MSE posts to convey important information. The body of your question should be self-contained. As for the mathematics: it is unclear what vector space you are working with. I suspect you are working in $\Bbb{R}^2$, with a typical element $(x, y)$ having the norm defined by $\|(x, y)\| = \max\{|x|, |y|\}$, but you don't make that clear.

Comment: This is not clear. Are you working on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? Is the norm of. a vector the element-wise max?